# a few listed issues with building a concentration game

Tags: javascript, html

I've been at this for a while and can't seem to crack it. I'm a beginner learning to code and I've put myself to the test to build a concentration game. I'm having the following issues;

1. I only have 11 tiles instead of 16.
2. I don't have any matching colours
3. My colours are locking into place when they should only do that when matched with their pair.

I look forward to seeing if someone more advanced can assist.

```js
var resetButton = document.getElementById("reset-button");

var colors= ["square-1" - "square-9"];
for (var i= 0; i < 10; i++){
    colors.push("square-" + i);
}


function GameSquare (el, color) {
    this.el= el;
    this.isOpen = false;
    this.isLocked= false;
    this.el.addEventListener("click", this, false);
    this.setColor(colors);
}

GameSquare.prototype.handleEvent = function(e) {
    switch (e.type) {
        case "click":
            if (this.isOpen || this.isLocked) {
                return;
            }
            this.isOpen = true;
            this.el.classList.add('flip');
            checkGame(this); 
    }
}
  
GameSquare.prototype.reset= function() {
    this.isOpen= false;
    this.isLocked= false;
    this.el.classList.remove('flip');
}

GameSquare.prototype.lock = function() {
    this.isLocked = true;
    this.isOpen = true;
}


GameSquare.prototype.setColor = function(color) {
    this.el.children[0].children[1].classList.remove(this.color);
    this.color = color;
    this.el.children[0].children[1].classList.add(color);
}

var gameSquares = [];

function random(n) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * n)
}

function getSomeColors() {
    var colorscopy = colors.slice();
    var randomColors = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        var index = random(colorscopy.length);
        randomColors.push(colorscopy.splice(index, 1)[0]);
    }
    return randomColors.concat(randomColors.slice());
}

function setupGame() {
    var array = document.getElementsByClassName("game-square");
    var randomColors = getSomeColors();
    for (var i= 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var index= random(randomColors.length);
        var color = randomColors.splice(index, 1)[0];
        gameSquares.push(new GameSquare(array[i], color));
    }
}

var firstSquare = null;

function checkGame (GameSquare) {
    if(firstSquare === null) {
        firstSquare = GameSquare;
        return
    }
    if (firstSquare.color === GameSquare.color) {
        firstSquare.lock();
        GameSquare.lock();
    } else {
        var a = firstSquare;
        var b = GameSquare;
        setTimeout(function() {
            a.reset();
            b.reset();
        }, 400);
    }
    firstSquare = null;
} 

function randomizeColors(){
    var randomColors= getSomeColors();
    gameSquares.forEach(function(GameSquare){
        var color = randomColors.splice(random(randomColors.length), 1)[0];
        GameSquare.setColor(color);
    });
}

function clearGame(){
    gameSquares.forEach(function(GameSquare) {
        gameSquares.reset();
    });
    setTimeout(function() {
        randomizeColors();
    }, 500);
}

setupGame()
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.game-square {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.game-square > div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    transition: 400ms;
}

.game-square > div > div {
    height: 50%;    
}

.game-square > div > div:first-child {
    background-color: grey;
}

.flip > div {
    top: -100%;
}


.square-0 {
    background-color: aqua;
  }
 
.square-1 {
    background-color: bisque;
  }
  
.square-2 {
    background-color: blue;
  }
  
.square-3 {
    background-color: blueviolet;
  }
  
.square-4 {
    background-color: brown;
  }
  
.square-5 {
    background-color: cadetblue;
  }
  
.square-6 {
    background-color: chartreuse;
  }
  
.square-7 {
    background-color: chocolate;
  }
  
.square-8 {
    background-color: coral;
  }
.square-9 {
  background-color: teal;
}

  #game {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    border: 1px solid red;
  }
  
  #game {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  }

  #reset-button{
    position: absolute;
    top: 90px;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Concentration Game</title>

<link href= "./styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type= "text/css">

</head>
<body>

        <div class="container">
            <div id="game">
                <div class= "game-square">
                  <div>
                    <div></div>
                    <div class= "square-0"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
                <div class= "game-square"> 
                  <div>
                    <div></div>
                    <div class= "square-1"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
                <div class= "game-square">
                  <div>
                    <div></div>
                    <div class= "square-2"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
                <div class= "game-square">
                  <div>
                    <div></div>
                    <div class= "square-3"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
                <div class= "game-square">
                  <div>
                    <div></div>
                    <div class= "square-4"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class= "game-square">
                <div>
                  <div></div>
                  <div class= "square-5"></div>
              </div>
          </div>
              <div class= "game-square">
                <div>
                  <div></div>
                  <div class= "square-6"></div>
              </div>
          </div>
              <div class= "game-square">
                <div>
                  <div></div>
                  <div class= "square-7"></div>
              </div>
          </div>
              <div class= "game-square">
                <div>
                  <div></div>
                  <div class= "square-8"></div>
              </div>
          </div>
              <div class= "game-square">
                <div>
                  <div></div>
                  <div class= "square-9"></div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class= "game-square">
            <div>
              <div></div>
              <div class= "square-0"><div>
          </div>
      </div>
          <div class= "game-square">
            <div>
              <div></div>
              <div class= "square-1"></div>
          </div>
      </div>
          <div class= "game-square">
            <div>
              <div></div>
              <div class= "square-2"></div>
          </div>
      </div>
          <div class= "game-square">
            <div>
              <div></div>
              <div class= "square-3"></div>
          </div>
      </div>
          <div class= "game-square">
            <div>
              <div></div>
              <div class= "square-4"></div>
          </div>
      </div>    
      </div>
      <button id="reset-button">Reset</button>
     </div>

<script src= "./script.js"></script>  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were very close. I am guessing the material you are reading is only focused on going up to 10 colors. These are the issues that pertain to this:

- By looking at your CSS, your `.square-X` classes only go up to 9. It should go up to 15 (0 index basis)
- In your JS, your colors initialization `for` loop condition is `i < 10`. It should be `i < 16` since you are targeting 16 colors.
- Also this particular line `var colors = ["square-1" - "square-9"];` is confusing. This is supposed to simply initialize an array but you are assigning it some kind of string value

By fixing these items, the memory game will work as expected. See demo below:

```js
var resetButton = document.getElementById("reset-button");

var colors = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
  colors.push("square-" + i);
}


function GameSquare(el, color) {
  this.el = el;
  this.isOpen = false;
  this.isLocked = false;
  this.el.addEventListener("click", this, false);
  this.setColor(color);
}

GameSquare.prototype.handleEvent = function(e) {
  switch (e.type) {
    case "click":
      if (this.isOpen || this.isLocked) {
        return;
      }
      this.isOpen = true;
      this.el.classList.add('flip');
      checkGame(this);
  }
}

GameSquare.prototype.reset = function() {
  this.isOpen = false;
  this.isLocked = false;
  this.el.classList.remove('flip');
}

GameSquare.prototype.lock = function() {
  this.isLocked = true;
  this.isOpen = true;
}


GameSquare.prototype.setColor = function(color) {
  this.el.children[0].children[1].classList.remove(this.color);
  this.color = color;
  this.el.children[0].children[1].classList.add(color);
}

var gameSquares = [];

function random(n) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * n)
}

function getSomeColors() {
  var colorscopy = colors.slice();
  var randomColors = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    var index = random(colorscopy.length);
    randomColors.push(colorscopy.splice(index, 1)[0]);
  }
  return randomColors.concat(randomColors.slice());
}

function setupGame() {
  var array = document.getElementsByClassName("game-square");
  var randomColors = getSomeColors();
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var index = random(randomColors.length);
    var color = randomColors.splice(index, 1)[0];
    gameSquares.push(new GameSquare(array[i], color));
  }
}

var firstSquare = null;

function checkGame(GameSquare) {
  if (firstSquare === null) {
    firstSquare = GameSquare;
    return
  }
  if (firstSquare.color === GameSquare.color) {
    firstSquare.lock();
    GameSquare.lock();
  } else {
    var a = firstSquare;
    var b = GameSquare;
    setTimeout(function() {
      a.reset();
      b.reset();
    }, 400);
  }
  firstSquare = null;
}

function randomizeColors() {
  var randomColors = getSomeColors();
  gameSquares.forEach(function(GameSquare) {
    var color = randomColors.splice(random(randomColors.length), 1)[0];
    GameSquare.setColor(color);
  });
}

function clearGame() {
  gameSquares.forEach(function(GameSquare) {
    gameSquares.reset();
  });
  setTimeout(function() {
    randomizeColors();
  }, 500);
}

setupGame()
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.game-square {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.game-square>div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transition: 400ms;
}

.game-square>div>div {
  height: 50%;
}

.game-square>div>div:first-child {
  background-color: grey;
}

.flip>div {
  top: -100%;
}

.square-0 {
  background-color: aqua;
}

.square-1 {
  background-color: bisque;
}

.square-2 {
  background-color: blue;
}

.square-3 {
  background-color: blueviolet;
}

.square-4 {
  background-color: brown;
}

.square-5 {
  background-color: cadetblue;
}

.square-6 {
  background-color: chartreuse;
}

.square-7 {
  background-color: chocolate;
}

.square-8 {
  background-color: coral;
}

.square-9 {
  background-color: teal;
}

.square-10 {
  background-color: hotpink;
}

.square-11 {
  background-color: khaki;
}

.square-12 {
  background-color: lime;
}

.square-13 {
  background-color: turquoise;
}

.square-14 {
  background-color: plum;
}

.square-15 {
  background-color: red;
}

#game {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#game {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#reset-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 90px;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div id="game">
      <div class="game-square">
        <div>
          <div></div>
          <div class=""></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="game-square">
        <div>
          <div></div>
          <div class="square"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="game-square">
        <div>
          <div></div>
          <div class="square"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="game-square">
        <div>
          <div></div>
          <div class="square"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="game-square">
        <div>
          <div></div>
          <div class="square"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="game-square">
        <div>
          <div></div>
          <div class="square"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="game-square">
        <div>
          <div></div>
          <div class="square"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="game-square">
        <div>
          <div></div>
          <div class="square"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="game-square">
        <div>
          <div></div>
          <div class="square"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="game-square">
        <div>
          <div></div>
          <div class="square"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="game-square">
        <div>
          <div></div>
          <div class="square"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="game-square">
        <div>
          <div></div>
          <div class="square"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="game-square">
        <div>
          <div></div>
          <div class="square"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="game-square">
        <div>
          <div></div>
          <div class="square"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="game-square">
        <div>
          <div></div>
          <div class="square"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="game-square">
        <div>
          <div></div>
          <div class="square"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <button id="reset-button">Reset</button>

</body>
```

Comment: That is unfortunate. Run my snippet. You will see that it works. You simply need to refactor some of your code according to what I have written. I have also made changes to the HTML based on your code. By adding square-x classes to the HTML, this will cause conflicts in the CSS classes prioritization. Since the JavaScript adds these classes, no need to add them initially on the HTML side.

Comment: Thank you 95faf8e76605e973 for your help. I have made the changes and seem to have the functionality running smooth I only have 1 problem. I am still only seeing 11 tiles instead of the 16 even after amending my code.

Comment: On your HTML side you need to have 16 `game-square`. You also need to make sure they follow correct HTML structure (i.e., all opening div tags must have corresponding closing div tags) and that the gamesquares have identical HTML structure. You can easily debug your HTML file if your format it using your text editor. You can also use https://www.freeformatter.com/html-validator.html to check if you have the correct format.

Comment: I ended up deleting some of the game square div's and re- copied and pasted them and that seemed to have done the trick. perhaps was a typo within those divs. not sure but it's all wroking perfect! thank you so much.

Comment: Yes, perhaps a missing closing `</div>`. You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

I made my own implementation with notes; you can compare to see different approach/techniques:

```js
//pick 8 colors
const colors = ["red","blue","green","yellow","orange","purple","brown","pink"];
//double the colors
const double = colors.concat(colors);
//randomize the colors
const matches = []; 
for(let i = 0; i < 16; i ++) {
  const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * double.length);
  matches.push(double.splice(random,1)[0]);
}

//create variable that houses id of comparing square
let compareTo;

//create global click disable
let disable = false; 

//on click function
function reveal(e) {
  //prevent spam click during comparison
  if(disable) return; 
  //shorten e.target.id to id
  const id = e.target.id; 
  //reveal clicked square
  e.target.classList.toggle("hidden");
  //remove its onclick
  e.target.onclick = null; 
  //if no squares being compared, store id 
  if(!compareTo){
    compareTo = id; 
  } else {
    //otherwise if square colors match
    if(matches[compareTo] === matches[id]){
      //reset id reference (keeping both reveal);
      compareTo = null; 
      //win condition
      if(!document.getElementsByClassName("hidden").length) setTimeout(()=>alert("YOU WIN!"),0);
    } else {
      //otherwise prevent spam click during reveal
      disable = true;
      //and hide both squares, must be in a timeout to be visible
      setTimeout(()=> {            
         e.target.classList.toggle("hidden");
         document.getElementById(compareTo).classList.toggle("hidden");
         //add onclick back
         e.target.onclick = ()=> reveal(event); 
         document.getElementById(compareTo).onclick = ()=> reveal(event); 
         //enable clicking
         disable = false;
         //and erase id reference;
         compareTo = null; 
      },750);      
    }
  }
}

//reference container for iteration
const container = document.getElementById("container"); 

//iterate squares rather than hard code into html
for(let i = 0; i < 16; i ++){
  const square = document.createElement("div");
  square.onclick = ()=> reveal(event); 
  square.classList.add("square");
  //add class that hides color
  square.classList.add("hidden");
  //ids match indexes of color matches
  square.setAttribute("id",i);
  //assign corresponding color
  square.style.backgroundColor = matches[i];
  container.append(square);
}
```

```css
#container {
width: 400px;
height: 400px;
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap; 
background: blue;
border: 1px solid black;
}

.square {
  width: 25%;
  height: 25%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}

.hidden {
   background-color: dimgray !important; 
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

</div>
```